# Why does a type switch on an error type not work?

Tags: go

The code:

```
type baseStruct struct {
    value int
}

type myStruct baseStruct

func checkType(value interface{}) {
    switch value.(type) {
    case myStruct:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a myStruct\n", value)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%v is something else\n", value)
    }
}

func main() {
    checkType(*new(baseStruct))
    checkType(myStruct(*new(baseStruct)))
}
```

outputs the following:

```
{0} is something else
{0} is a myStruct
```

https://play.golang.org/p/f8GjAe_Pc2l

Same for primitive types: https://play.golang.org/p/sD320wtkAs2

And yet the code:

```
type myError error

func checkType(value interface{}) {
    switch value.(type) {
    case myError:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a myError\n", value)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%v is something else\n", value)
    }
}

func main() {
    checkType(fmt.Errorf("TEST1"))
    checkType(myError(fmt.Errorf("TEST2")))
}
```

outputs the following:

```
TEST1 is a myError
TEST2 is a myError
```

https://play.golang.org/p/g6ZmSv3hDzA

Why does a type switch work on everything except an error?

Comment: I think the answer can be found in the docs on [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions): *" if T is not an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x is identical to the type T. In this case, T must implement the (interface) type of x; otherwise the type assertion is invalid since it is not possible for x to store a value of type T. **If T is an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x implements the interface T.**"*

Comment: @mkopriva you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

using composite struct you can match error, myError or something else easily.

error and myError are exclusive within the same switch statement, but it should not be a problem.

Instantiation is slightly different `myError{error:fmt.Errorf("TEST2")}`.

You do not need to use a ptr *myError (ie `&myError..`) as error is an interface, thus it will match the method set defined on the value receiver of your type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type myError struct {
    error
}

func checkType(value interface{}) {
    switch value.(type) {
    case myError:
        fmt.Printf("%v is a myError\n", value)
    // case error:
    //  fmt.Printf("%v is a %T\n", value, value)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%v is something else\n", value)
    }
}

func main() {
    checkType(fmt.Errorf("TEST1"))
    checkType(myError{error:fmt.Errorf("TEST2")})
}
```

outputs

```
TEST1 is something else
TEST2 is a myError
```